# One string contains another without one character containing

Tags: java

I want to compare two `strings` and make them `title.contains(starName) = true` if for example there is one error in `title`:

```
String title = "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood - Brad Pett";
String starName = "Brad Pitt";

public static boolean containsWithoutOneCharacter(String title , String starName) {

        if ... 

        ...

        return true;
    }
```

The `starName` could be placed anywhere in the title.
I really don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to take two or three pointers at first.
One of them will iterate over starName and the other one over title. The other one will step in later. Also you can use a int flag for the different character.

You should iterate over title. When you see the first letter of the starName, you should look the next letter:

- if it is the starName's second letter; then iterate through it;
- else, you should look at the one next letter in case if the second letter of the starName is missing.

In the end of the iteration, if you find the starName with the defined condition; you have no problem. Else, you should iterate from second letter of starName in case if the first letter of the starName is missing.

Of course, you can make this algorithm better and efficient with String operations in Java. It may be a good starting point for this problem.